# Why is my Java project not found in my workspace (Visual Studio Code)?

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code

My Java extensions do not seem to be able to actually recognize my project as a Java project. As a result, my project management, linter and formatter extensions do not work.. I use the Java extension pack from Microsoft along with the Java language support extension by Red Hat.

[image]

[image]

It might have something to do with the fact that I renamed my package from 'productestservice' to 'producttestservice'. I tried an answer from a related thread, which is to 'clean the Java language server workspace'. Unfortunately, this did not solve the issue.

[Here](https://github.com/cassis163/workspace-issue/tree/main) is a repository that I prepared for the reproduction of this issue.

**EDIT: I found out that my language server extension fails to scan my project.**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that a folder named 'postgres-data' (generated from my PostgreSQL database) has strict permissions that disallowed my project manager extension to scan my project. A workaround is to run `chmod 777 -R postgres-data`.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the [Project Manager for Java](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-dependency) extension,The effect is as follows

[image]